# Next.js, getInitialProps do not work

Tags: javascript, next.js

when pages are rendered at server-site at first time or refresh the rendered page, getInitialProps do not work:

```
Home.getInitialProps = async ({store}) => {
    axios.post('/user').then(res => {
        var user = res.data;
        store.dispatch(setLoggingState(user));
    }, res => {
        console.log('4444');
    })
    return {};
}
```

In above code, server always print ‘4444’，and express did not receive the 'POST' request. tanks for your help

Comment: Why do you pass two functions to the `then` callback? Also, you need to use an absolute URL for requests inside `getInitialProps`.

Comment: @FabianSchultz thanks，and i hava another question, why did express-session generate a new session, when i open a new tab of browser or fresh them？

Answer (score 1):

1. As @Fabian Schultz said, request url must be absolute in the
   `getInitialProps`, because a relative url cannot work on the server-side.
2. The `getInitialProps` method should use `async` and `await`, like this:

   ```
   Home.getInitialProps = async ({store}) => {
     await axios.post('/user').then(res => {
       var user = res.data;
       store.dispatch(setLoggingState(user));
     }, res => {
       console.log('4444');
     });
     return {};
   }
   ```